# Externally created parametrized derived type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I would like to create a parametrized derived type inside a procedure and operate on the type's member. The following code works and writes out `4` and `8`, as expected.

```
module mod1
  implicit none
  type :: pdt(n)
    integer, len :: n
    integer :: a(n), b(n)
  end type
end module mod1

program main
  use mod1
  implicit none
  type(pdt(4)) :: aa

  print *, aa%n
  print *, func(4)

  contains
    integer function func(n) result(m)
      integer :: n
      type(pdt(n)) :: pdttest

      m = 2*pdttest%n
    end function
end program
```

The problem arises when I place the procedure `func` in a separate module, in which case `pdttest%n` is uninitialized. Compiling using gfortran 11.2.0 with the flag `-Wall` returns:
`Warning: ‘pdttest.n’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]`
What could be the cause of this?

```
 module mod2
  use mod1
  implicit none
  contains
    integer function func(n) result(m)
      integer :: n
      type(pdt(n)) :: pdttest

      m = 2*pdttest%n
    end function
end module
```

Comment: I have edited the question to explain the issue. `pdttest%n` does not seem to be set correctly.

Comment: Which version of gfortran are you using? If not the latest, please update and try again. (Automatic objects of parameterized type are things compilers often find tricky to get right first time.)

Comment: The code does *not* work as expected with GNU Fortran (GCC) 11.1.0 Looks like a bug, but this is not the very latest version of the compiler

Comment: I haven't tested with 12, but works in 8, 9, 10 and fails in 11. Simply: compiler bug, please report to vendor as regression (but test with 12 if you can).